# Is there something like python's ast.literal_eval() in Scala?

Tags: scala, literals

I'm trying to parse strings that look like:

```
info_string = "[(1, 10, 10, 2), (2, 20, 12, 3), (3, 42, 53, 1)]"
```

and I would like to get a list of arrays, i.e.

```
info_list = [(1, 10, 10, 2), (2, 20, 12, 3), (3, 42, 53, 1)]
```

In python I would just do

```
import ast

info_list = ast.literal_eval(info_string)
```

Is there similar functionality in Scala?